# require.js doesn't trigger the callback function sometimes

Tags: javascript, module, callback, requirejs

Well, this is like my third question about require.js in two days, well the problem is that I have a project with the following modules:

1. main.js
2. res.js
3. juego.js

And in the main file the callback that must be called once all the modules are loaded **sometimes is triggered and sometimes it is not**.

I'm not going to post any code because I don't believe that something is wrong with it, but I have to mention that it couldn't be an issue of the load order because my files doesn't have any dependency from each other. It is *really* weird, and my files are not too big (first has 73 lines and the second one 18)

So the question is, what could be wrong? a require.js bug or something else?

EDIT: here is the code of my modules:

main.js:

```
require
(
    ['cliente/juego', 'cliente/res'], 
    function (juego, res) 
    {
        function main () 
        {
            alert('ok');
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', main, false);
    }
);
```

res.js:

```
define
(
    function () 
    {
        return (function () 
        {
            var recursos = 
            {
                soldado : { ruta : 'res/imagenes/soldados/1.png', tipo : 'Image', fuente : null }
            };
            var metodos = {};
            var cargados = 0;
            var totales = 0;
            var listos = false; // Todavía no se han cargado los recursos

            function terminarCarga (evento) 
            {
                // Cada vez que se cargue un recurso se incrementará el progreso
                cargados++;

                if (cargados == totales) 
                {
                    listos = true; // Recursos cargados y listos para usarse

                    // Acción a seguir una vez cargados todos los recursos
                }
            }

            metodos.getTotales = function () 
            {
                return totales;
            }

            metodos.getListos = function () 
            {
                return listos;
            }

            metodos.cargar = function () 
            {
                // Carga todos los recursos

                var recurso;

                for (var i in recursos) 
                {
                    totales++;
                    recurso = recursos[ i ];

                    if (recurso.tipo == 'Image') 
                    {
                        recurso.fuente = new Image;
                        recurso.fuente.onload = terminarCarga;
                        recurso.fuente.src = recurso.ruta;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        recurso.fuente = new Audio;
                        recurso.fuente.addEventListener('loadeddata', terminarCarga, false);
                        recurso.fuente.src = recurso.ruta;
                    }
                }
            }

            metodos.get = function (nombre) 
            {
                return recursos[ nombre ].fuente;
            }

            return metodos;
        })();
    }
);
```

juego.js:

```
define
(
    function () 
    {
        return (function () 
        {
            var metodos = {};
            metodos.getContexto = function () 
            {
                // Recordar llamar ésta función una vez cargada la página
                this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
                this.contexto = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            }

            return metodos;
        })();
    }
);
```

The alert in the main function only popups in the 10% of all the cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not with RequireJS or how you use RequireJS. The problem is that sometimes the `load` event happens *before* `window.addEventListener('load', main, false);` is executed. I bet if you change the body of your `main.js`  to the following, it will always work:

```
require(['cliente/juego', 'cliente/res'], function (juego, res) {
    console.log('ok');
});
```

You might want to use the [`domReady` plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload), which takes care of problems like this. Something like:

```
require(['domReady', 'cliente/juego', 'cliente/res'], function (domReady, juego, res) {
    domReady(function () {
        alert('ok');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! yes it was a problem with the DOM, I implemented the *domReady* solution and it works in the 100% of the cases. Thank's to Bill also for taking time to respond, it was very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen random load errors before, don't know if that's the cause of what you're seeing or not. If so, have a look at this; sometimes the web server itself is the culprit. It was in my case, anyway.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/requirejs/x5Z-eZMzKwI/rbOSMNULftgJ

EDIT:

The callback is definitely being called, every time. I changed the code in main so it looks like this:

```
require(
    ['cliente/juego', 'cliente/res'], 

    function (juego, res) {
        console.log(juego, res);

        function main () {
            alert('ok');
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', main, false);
    }
);
```

And I'm getting this output in the console:

```
Object {getContexto: function}

Object {getTotales: function, getListos: function, cargar: function, get: function}
```

EDIT:

I think this is what you're looking for: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload

Comment: This happens with Chrome and Firefox, and the weird thing is that I don't see any log error / message :/

Comment: Any way I could see it?

Comment: The error? it doesn't throw any error, like I said it is weird, but I noticed that it doesn't work when I refresh, and when I open in a new tab it triggers, there is only a 90% of approach that the script run when refreshing.

Comment: require.js has some other weird issues too, for example when I declare the same singletons I just showed above with the call brackets in different lines it returns undefined, but runs ok in my current model.